# Identify card game similar to Kalookie

Tags: identify-this-game, rummy

Several years ago I was taught a card game that was called "Oh Sh*t." 
Recently I looked it up online and found another card game with the same name, but completely different rules, so I'm hoping someone on BG.SE knows what the game I was taught should actually be called.

**Overview**

- Cards - 2 x Standard 52 card decks + Jokers
- Jokers and 2's are wild cards
- Each round, players are dealt 11 cards.

A full game consists of 8 rounds, with the ending condition for each round being the first person to play (lay down) all their cards.

Play within each round is regulated based on a contract to which each player must conform, before they are able to play their hands:

- Round 1 - 1 set of 3 cards
- Round 2 - 2 sets of 3 cards
- Round 3 - 1 set of 4 cards
- Round 4 - 2 sets of 4 cards
- Round 5 - 1 set of 5 cards
- Round 6 - 2 sets of 5 cards
- Round 7 - 1 set of 6 cards
- Round 8 - 2 sets of 6 cards

A "set" is a series of cards of the same rank, but runs of values are not permitted (eg, a set of 7, 8, 9 is not allowed) - wild cards (the jokers and 2's) can substitute for any card needed to complete the set, but there must never be more wild cards in the set than actual value cards.

Players are also issued 10 buys/lives at the beginning of the game, with which they can purchase additional cards from the deck at the beginning of their turn.

At the end of each round, scores are tallied, and accumulated until all rounds are completed.

If you can shed some light on the real name for this game, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a contract rummy game called [Farmer's Rummy](http://www.pagat.com/rummy/telefunken.html#farmers) that sounds like what you're describing.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a bunch!